# 2 items using same layout

Tags: html, css

i want to create a layout on my items that every child in my div is aligned same height as it is in the other item div.

[image: as shown here] i tried doing it with grid:

```css
.textgrid { grid-row: 2; }
    
.profilegrid { grid-row: 1; }
    
.imagesgrid { grid-row: 3; }
    
.deletegrid { grid-row: 4; }
    
.gridhandler { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: max-content auto min-content max-content;
}
```

.gridhandler is the div that is a child in the whole list. [image: img]

does anybody know how i can align all the grid rows at the same height even if one of the texts is longer than one other?

regards,
Sebastian

Comment: use flexbox in parent, add position relative in child with height 100%.

Comment: i do also want that the delete button is on bottom everytime